# Table header not sticky in Microsoft Edge and Brave

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the table header sticky on scroll. My solution is working fine in Chrome and Firefox but its not working in *Edge* and *Brave Browser*.

I've tried other things like making table header absolute, but it disturbs the table structure.
I have no idea how to make this cross browser compatible.

Here is the jsfiddle link of the code.
https://jsfiddle.net/zp1Lk6mw/

Here's the code

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-wrapper table-1">
                <div  id="table-1-container" class="table-container">
                    <table class="table">

                <thead id="table-1-head">
                    <tr class="table-header">
                        <th>Column 1</th>
                        <th>Column 2</th>
                        <th>Column 3</th>
                        <th>Column 4</th>
                        <th>Column 5</th>
                        <th>Column 6</th>
                        <th>Column 7</th>
                        <th>Column 8</th>
                        <th>Column 9</th>
                        <th>Column 10</th>
                        <th>Column 11</th>
                        <th>Column 12</th>
                        <th>Column 13</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>                       <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sheet1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div>22359555555555555555555555555555555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>223595555</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                            <td><div>1871265.91</div></td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
:root {
    --orange: #f47a14;
    --blue-header: #003f5b;
    --dark-grey: #999999;
    --light-grey: #f8f8fc;
    --text-color: #333333;
}

.table-wrapper {
    margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.table-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 610px;
    position: relative;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
}

.table-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 2px;
}

.table-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px var(--dark-grey);
}


.table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

table.table thead {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
  
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 var(--dark-grey);
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    top: -5px;
    background-color: #fff;
  
}

table.table tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 610px;
    border-width: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table tr {
    height: 30px;
}

.table tr th:nth-child(1) {
    width: 14.284% !important;
}

.table th {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    color: var(--blue-header);
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.table tr td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 14.284% !important;
    max-width: 14.284% !important;
}

.table td {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    padding-right: 15px;
}

td div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;

    scrollbar-width: none;
  scrollbar-color: transparent;
}

.table tr.table-header {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    width: 100%;
}

.table tr:not(.table-header):nth-child(even) {
    background-color: var(--light-grey);
}

.table tr td div::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0px;
}
.table tr td div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    background-color: var(--dark-grey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stickiness requires `position: relative` which does not applies to `thead` or `tr` but it does applies to `th` so you can do:

```
table th{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

this will make the table header sticky.